# How to efficiently create and compile large map in c++

Tags: python, c++, json, enums, maps

Currently, I have multiple json files and a python code which reads one of the json file, main.json, and creates a full c++ code based off of the json file. Within the main() of that c++, I need to convert a number output to a string using numberToString.json. I cannot find a way to successfully compile the c++ code in time (<1 minute)

I created a nested map "std::map< std::string, std::map< std::string, std::string>> enumMap" in c++ file and populated with all the values from numberToString.json (~20,000 values), but the code does not compile in time (I shut it down after ~5 minutes. CMAKE uses gcc 4.8.5 to compile.)

Example code:

```
main.json
    {"example" : {
       "FRUIT" : "ex_fruit"
    }, 
    ...
    }}
```

```
numberToString.json
    {"FRUIT" : {
       "1" : "fresh",
       ...,
       "10" : "not fresh"
    },
    ...
    }}
```

```
someHeader.h
    typedef struct FRUIT
    {
       int     val;
    };

    typedef struct Example
    {
       FRUIT   ex_fruit;
    };
```

```
python.py
    def someFunc(typename) 
    //input is struct name in string ex."Example"
       "already implemented"
       return memberVariables
       //returns member variable accessors

    print "#include \"someHeader.h\""
    print "int main() {"
    print "   Example ex = {1};"
    print "   printf(%s, %s);" %("%s", someFunc("Example")
    print "return 0;"
    print "}"
```

```
pythonOutput.cxx
    #include "someHeader.h"
    int main() {
       Example ex = {1};
       printf(%s, ***ex.ex_fruit.val***);
       return 0;
    }
```

So on pythonOutput.cxx, I need ***ex.ex_fruit.val***, which is 1, to come out as ***"fresh"*** by using numberToString.json.

I am using python 2.7

Comment: Why do you need to generate C++ code from python?  It seems like it would make more sense to either do all of your processing in python or use one of the many available JSON libraries for C++ and do all of your processing there.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely NOT be auto-generating C++ code that hard-codes a map like that. There are libraries to read json files directly into C++ (see [rapid json](http://rapidjson.org/) for example), and these should be used instead. The code will compile much faster, and the amount of time it takes to read in 20,000 files should be on the order of a few milliseconds (instead of the >5 minutes it's taking to compile).

If you want to avoid adding a dependency on a json parser in your C++ code, I recommend transforming the JSON file into a simpler format that's easier to read with C++.

### A very very simple format to read and write maps from files

Let's take a simple map:

```
map<string, map<string, string>> test_map {
    {"Hello", {
        {"A", "B"}, 
        {"C", "D"}}},
    {"World", {
        {"Blarg", "glug glug glug"}, 
        {"idek what to put here", "felt cute might delete later"}}}};
```

We're going to write it to a file using a very simple format. Strings will be written as `<string length> <string text>`, and maps will be written as `<map length> <map key-value pairs>`. So, for example, `"Hello world"` would be written as `11 Hello world`. For the above map, the corresponding file is

```
2 5 Hello2 1 A1 B1 C1 D5 World2 5 Blarg14 glug glug glug21 idek what to put here28 felt cute might delete later
```

You have the 2, which means that the top level map has 2 elements. This is followed by a 5, which means that the first key has 5 characters in it. This is followed by the keys and values of the first map, etc.

#### Writing maps to a file in this format

Because the format is so simple, this is also very simple to do.

```
namespace output {
    using std::map; 
    using std::string; 
    void write(FILE* file, string const& str) {
        // Write the length of the string, followed by a space
        fprintf(file, "%lu ", str.size());

        // Write the string itself
        fwrite(str.data(), 1, str.size(), file);  
    }

    template<class Key, class Value>
    void write(FILE* file, map<Key, Value> const& m) {
        // Write the length of the map, followed by a space
        fprintf(file, "%lu ", m.size()); 

        for(auto& entry : m) {
            // Write the key
            write(file, entry.first);

            // Write the value
            write(file, entry.second); 
        }
    }
}
```

#### Reading maps from a file

This is also very simple to do. To read a string, for example, we read the length, and then we read all the characters.

```
namespace input {
    using std::map;
    using std::string; 

    void read(FILE* file, size_t& length) {
        int result = fscanf(file, "%lu ", &length);
        if(result < 0) throw std::logic_error("Couldn't read from file"); 
    }

    void read(FILE* file, string& str) {

        size_t length;      // Read the length
        read(file, length); 

        str.resize(length); 
        size_t n_read = fread(&str[0], 1, length, file); // Read the characters

        if(n_read != length) { // Handle errors
            throw std::logic_error("Unable to read entirety of string from file"); 
        }
    }

    template<class Key, class Value>
    void read(FILE* file, map<Key, Value>& text) {
        size_t length;      // Read the length of the map
        read(file, length); 
        text.clear(); 

        for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            Key key;
            read(file, key);        // Read the key
            read(file, text[key]);  // Read the value
        }
    }
}
```

#### Using this code

To write a map:

```
void write_map(string file, map<string, map<string, string>> test_map) {
    auto output_file = fopen(file.c_str(), "w"); 
    output::write(output_file, test_map); 
    fclose(output_file); 
}
```

To read a map:

```
map<string, map<string, string>> read_map(string file) {
    auto input_file = fopen(file.c_str(), "r"); 
    map<string, map<string, string>> m;
    input::read(file, m); 
    fclose(input_file); 
    return m; 
}
```

#### Testing this code

[**You can see a live demonstration here**](https://godbolt.org/z/U7-q4Y)

This main function will write a test map to a file, then read it back into a different map, then compare the two.

```
int main() {
    using std::map; 
    using std::string; 
    map<string, map<string, string>> test_map {
        {"Hello", {{"A", "B"}, {"C", "D"}}},
        {"World", {{"Blarg", "glug glug glug"}, {"idek what to put here", "felt cute might delete later"}}}
    }; 

    {
        auto output_file = fopen("example.txt", "w"); 
        output::write(output_file, test_map); 
        fclose(output_file); 
    }
    map<string, map<string, string>> map_from_file; 
    {
        auto input_file = fopen("example.txt", "r");
        try {
            input::read(input_file, map_from_file); 
        } catch(std::logic_error& err) {
            std::cerr << "Reading example.txt failed: " << err.what() << '\n'; 
        }
        fclose(input_file);  
    }

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "Maps equivilant? " << (test_map == map_from_file) << '\n'; 


    for(auto pair : map_from_file) {
        std::cout << '"' << pair.first << "\" -> {\n"; 
        for(auto kv : pair.second) {
            std::cout << "  \"" << kv.first << "\" -> \"" << kv.second << '"' << "\n"; 
        }
        std::cout << "}\n"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I cannot have any outside-server dependency. (So cannot use rapid json). Even if I transforme JSON file into simpler format, don't I still need to create some find of data structure, such as a map, to get key-value pairs?

Comment: "_I cannot have any outside-server dependency_" - @Anaguone Downloading rapidjson or nlohmann/json doesn't add such a dependency. You download it once and can then cut the internet cable if you'd like.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, By above line, I meant I cannot download anything into the server I am working in.

Comment: Why? It's only text files. If the person who put that restriction in place is willing to rethink, you'd solve this in no-time. What libraries are already installed on the server you are talking about? You may already have a JSON lib pre-installed. If not, do as Antonio suggested and transform the json data into a simple file format that you can then create a parser for in C++.

Comment: @Mikan I updated the post to give an example of how one might write or read maps to and from a very simple file format.